# 404 error when trying to download Nuget package from artifacts feed

Tags: azure-artifacts

We have a functional artifacts feed that I (as an administrator/owner) am able to install nuget packages from using `Install-PSResource`, however one of my colleagues is unable to install packages the same way, even though he has created a personal access token with package read permissions, and he is able to see the packages on the Azure DevOps web page. When he tries to install or list packages that are available on the feed, he gets a 404 error.

The feed is project-scoped, and I have confirmed that he has permissions to the project, both on the feed and the relevant views on the feed.